# Regular expression error: no ending delimiter

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to execute this regular expression:

```
<?php
    preg_match("/^([^\x00-\x1F]+?){0,1}/", 'test string');
?>
```

But keep getting an error:

```
Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '/' found in /var/www/preg.php on line 6
```

I can't understand where it is coming from. I have an ending delimeter right there... I tried to change delimiter to other symbols and it didn't help.

I would appreciate your help on this problem.

Comment: What are you trying to match? `+?){0,1}` doesn't make a lot of sense. The `+` means you want at least on occurrence of the preceding match, the `?` means one or none occurrence of the preceding match and `{0,1}` means the same as `?`. So what are you trying to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like `Gumbo` said, `preg_match` is not binary safe.

Use instead:

```
preg_match("/^([^\\x{00}-\\x{1F}]+?){0,1}/", 'test string'));
```

This is the correct way to specify Unicode code points in PCRE.

Comment: Thank you for example. I used your variant.

Answer (score 4):

I guess PHP chokes on the [NULL character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) that denotes the end of a string in C.

Try it with single quotes so that `\x00` is interpreted by the PCRE engine and not by PHP:

```
'/^([^\x00-\x1F]+?){0,1}/'
```

It seems that this is an already known bug (see [*Problems with strings containing \x00*](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=16590)).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about php, but maybe the problem is that you need to escape your backslashes?
try `"/^([^\\x00-\\x1F]+?){0,1}/"`

Comment: it could be that \x00 gets interpreted as end of string before it gets handed over to the regex engine